# Why my for loop is returning me only 1 value

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, discord.js

I have a web scraping but and I search for a match with an array that I have with values and the array that I get in the scraping, I iterate those arrays with a for loop the thing is I just having only 1 value when there are more than 1 match in the arrays, I'd like to get all the values not only the first match.

My code.

```
        let dataJobs = await page.evaluate(()=>{
            var a = document.getElementById("task-listing-datatable").getAttribute("data-tasks"); //Search job list
            var ar = eval(a);//Convert string to arr
            var keyword = ['Image Annotation', 'What Is The Best Dialogue Category About Phones', 'Label Roads( With Sidewalks) In Images']; //This is the list where I'll find match 
          for(let i=0; i<ar.length; i++){ //hago la busqueda de coincidencia
            for(let j=0; j<keyword.length; j++){
                if(ar[i][1] === keyword[j]){
                  let jobMatch =`${ar[i][0]} - ${ar[i][1]} - Paga: ${ar[i][3]} - Numero de Tasks: ${ar[i][5]} @everyone`; //return the Match
                          return jobMatch;
                  }
            }
          }
          
          });
```

Here is all the code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const url = 'url';
var coincidence = [];

(async () => {
    const URL = url
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        'args' : [
          '--no-sandbox',
          '--disable-setuid-sandbox'
        ]
      });
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(URL, { 'waitUntil' : 'networkidle2' });
      console.log("Primer coincidence " + coincidence);
    client.on('message', async message =>{ //When the word start is written, run this:
        if(message.channel.id === '613553889433747477'){
            if(message.content.startsWith('start')) {
                let dataJobs = await page.evaluate(()=>{
                    var a = document.getElementById("task-listing-datatable").getAttribute("data-tasks"); //Search job list
                    var ar = eval(a);//Convert string to arr
                    var keyword = ['Image Annotation', 'What Is The Best Dialogue Category About Phones', 'Label Roads( With Sidewalks) In Images']; //This is the list where I'll find match 
                  for(let i=0; i<ar.length; i++){ //search the coincidence
                    for(let j=0; j<keyword.length; j++){
                        if(ar[i][1] === keyword[j]){
                          let jobMatch =`${ar[i][0]} - ${ar[i][1]} - Paga: ${ar[i][3]} - Numero de Tasks: ${ar[i][5]} @everyone`; //return the Match
                                  return jobMatch;
                          }
                    }
                  }
                  
                  });
                
                console.log(dataJobs);
                console.log(`==== first login ====`)
                console.log(`==================`)

                          if(!coincidence.includes(dataJobs)){ //If there is no coincidence, send the message
                            client.channels.get(`613573853565681671`).send(dataJobs);
                            coincidence.push(dataJobs);
                          }else{//else do not send it 
                            console.log("It was sent")
                          }
            }
        }
        await page.reload();
    })    
    

    
})()

client.on('message', (message)=>{
    if(message.content == '!interval'){
        setInterval(()=>{
            client.channels.get(`613553889433747477`).send(`start`);
        },10000);
    }
});

client.login('token');
```

I just get 1 value of all values I want to get

Comment: return statements are for `methods`, not `for loops`.  As soon as you hit a return statement in a for loop, it will exit all the way out of the method it is inside.

Comment: So, how i can have all the values in the let dataJobs?

Comment: Take a look at `Array.prototype.map`, possibly paired with `Array.prototype.filter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this

```
  let dataJobs = await page.evaluate(()=>{
      var a = document.getElementById("task-listing-datatable").getAttribute("data-tasks"); //Search job list
      var ar = eval(a);//Convert string to arr
      var keyword = ['Image Annotation', 'What Is The Best Dialogue Category About Phones', 'Label Roads( With Sidewalks) In Images']; //This is the list where I'll find match 
      let ret = [] ;
      ar.forEach(val => { if (keyword.includes(val[1])) { ret.push(`${val[0]} - ${val[1]} - Paga: ${val[3]} - Numero de Tasks: ${val[5]} @everyone`)} } )    

      return ret ; 

  });
```

**Ps: Instead of using eval please use JSON.parse(a) to prevent javascript code injection .**

Answer (score 0):

why not try and save the result of the match in a dynamic array instead of returning the value, something like a global array:

```
let array = [];
let dataJobs = await page.evaluate(()=>{
    var a = document.getElementById("task-listing-datatable").getAttribute("data-tasks"); //Search job list
    var ar = eval(a);//Convert string to arr
    var keyword = ['Image Annotation', 'What Is The Best Dialogue Category About Phones', 'Label Roads( With Sidewalks) In Images']; //This is the list where I'll find match 
  for(let i=0; i<ar.length; i++){ //hago la busqueda de coincidencia
    for(let j=0; j<keyword.length; j++){
        if(ar[i][1] === keyword[j]){
          let jobMatch =`${ar[i][0]} - ${ar[i][1]} - Paga: ${ar[i][3]} - Numero de Tasks: ${ar[i][5]} @everyone`; //return the Match
                  array.push(jobMatch);
          }
    }
  }

  });
```

Comment: This throws me an error, it says "array is not defined"

Comment: where did you declare the array? for the array to be global it needs to be declared outside all functions, that means declare it in the same place you have declared your, url, client, coincidence...etc variables